# Alfresco русификация сообщений

Tags: alfresco

Доброго времени суток всем.
Столкнулся с проблемой при освоении alfresco. Подключил и настроил возможность отправки пользователю сообщений на мейл, о выдачи ему задания, по умолчанию шаблон сообщения на английском, изменив тело сообщения на русский, в письме отображаются иероглифы. Почитав гугл, нашел только русификацию версий 4,2 а у меня 5,1. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как то решить сложившеюся ситуацию?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в версии Alfresco. Русификация и для 4.2, и для 5.1 делается одинаково. Для локализации обновите шаблон в репозитории (второй способ, описанный в http://ossportal.ru/technologies/alfresco/blogs/624). Если проблема именно в кодировке - перед загрузкой в Alfresco сохраните у себя на компьютере этот шаблон в utf8, а не cp1251.

Comment: С этим разобрался своими силами ) спасибо большое Но походу освоения, столкнулся с еще одном проблемой, опять же русификации. Поставил себе модуль avlex. При истечении времени отведенного на задачу, ежедневно на почту приходит уведомление, на английском, я ни как не могу найти, где хранится шаблон этого уведомления, что бы поправить его, не подскажите где он лежит?

Comment: Вообще - отдельный вопрос, сейчас придут злые модераторы и все удалят.
Нужно в `alfresco-global.properties` добавить строки по аналогии с https://github.com/ITDSystems/alvex-business-calendar/blob/e80ad81b3da30c1f15dfb0157b558c7705a2c25b/repo/src/main/amp/config/alfresco/module/business-calendar/alfresco-global.properties, указав, где лежат шаблоны. Складываете их в tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco и дальше структуру папок. Файлы, которые надо перевести: https://github.com/ITDSystems/alvex-business-calendar/tree/master/repo/src/main/resources/com/alvexcore/bcal

Comment: Наконец снова дошли руки, что бы доделать все. Нашел все что нужно русифицировать, перевел все сообщения, но при приходе сообщений (именно сообщений alvex) вместо букв иероглифы. Я так понимаю, надо где то либо добавить либо изменить кодировку, но не могу найти где. Стандартные сообщения о постановке новой задачи приходят на русском в нормальном виде. Подскажите пожалуйста, куда смотреть